# Difference between function returning State Integer () and State Int Integer

Tags: haskell, integer, state, controls, monads

I am relatively new to Haskell and have struggled to find some clarification on this confusion.

Given a function that takes an Integer as an input, what would be the difference between the function returning `State Integer ()`  and  `State Int Integer`.

I think I am right in understanding that `State Int Integer` requires me to return the result using the `pure` function.

When I try to write a function of `func :: Integer -> State Integer ()` I get the error `No instance for (Num ()) arising from the literal ‘0’`, as I try to use `pure` to return the value 0.

Comment: The `a` in `State a b` is the type of the state, `b` is what the function "returns".

Comment: Can you show how your `func` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

First of all a common misconception is that `State a b` *contains* state. It does not, it *changes* a state. Indeed, something of a `State a b` will take a state of type `a` might change the state (to pass to the next `State` object), and might "return" some value of type `b`.

If you thus have a function `helper1 :: State Int String` for example, and a function `helper2 :: String -> State Int ()` you can pass the `String` that will be returned by the `State` object of `helper1` to construct a `State` object of `helper2`, so you can make a function:

```
func :: State Int ()
func = do
  s <- helper1
  helper2 s
```

Both `helper1` and `helper2 s` can read the state that will be passed, modify the state, or might for example return the state. But nor `func`, `helper1` and `helper2` *contain* a state. What you can do is work with [**`runState :: State s a -> s -> (s, a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.6/docs/Data-Sequence-Internal.html#v:runState). Here you provide an initial state, and you run that state through `func` for example. We can thus call `runState func 0` to run this "through" `func` with initial state `0`. It will then return a 2-tuple with the state *after* it has passed through `func` and what `func` returns (in this case the unit value).